# File uploading certain MIME Types

Tags: html, file-upload, mime-types, csv

I'm trying to allow only .tsv files visible for upload. It's a valid MIME Type, so I'm not sure why it isn't working. Can you help?

```
<input type="file" accept="text/tab-separated-values" />
```

Comment: The browser will have to recognize that .tsv files have a mime type of `text/tab-separated-values` for that to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 function checkfile(inputVal) {

     var validExts = ".tsv";
     var fileExt = inputVal.value;

     fileExt = fileExt.substring(fileExt.lastIndexOf('.'));

     if (validExts.indexOf(fileExt) < 0) {
        alert("Invalid file selected. ");
        return false;
     }
     else return true;
  }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

hmm check out this [link](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html)
just to be sure that your mime type is correct

Answer (score 0):

The Mime-Type tells the server which protocol to use to process the information given. I've always done this as validation on the server side by only accepting file name(s) that end with .tsv

If you do not want to do this server side, you can write some javascript to look at the value of the input field before you submit to make sure it ends with .tsv